# Z Score Alternative for Asymmetric Distribtions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I would like to find the Z score for an asymmetric distribution.

Problem with using the standard formula is that it is for normal distributions.

If used in my case, the generated score for a given value would be off.

What techniques can be applied to get a proper Z score?